# funciones a partir de strings en python

Tags: python, funciones, sintaxis

Se podría ejecutar un comando de la siguiente manera?

```py
accion = 'abrir'
abrir()
```

es decir, tu das el comando y lo que das se ejecuta como función.
En otras palabras, se puede convertir un string en la estructura del programa¿? Gracias de antemano.
Lo que no quiero hacer es:

```py
accion = input('dime que hacer')
if accion == 'abrir':
    abrir()
```

Comment: no seria mejor poner un condicional ejemplo `if( accion == 'abrir'): abrir()`

Comment: eso es exactamente lo que quiero evitar

Comment: puedes utilizar `eval()` pero es sumanente peligroso lo mejor es hacerlo con condicionales!

Comment: lo probaré, mientras no detroze mi pc xd. gracias @Bryro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías simular una estructura de control switch ya que en python no existe dicha estructura, de la siguiente manera

```
def suma(a, b):
    return a + b

def resta(a, b):
    return a - b

def multiplicacion(a, b):
    return a * b

def division(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return "Error: Division entre cero..."
    else:
        return a / b

def default():
    return "Opcion Invalida"

"""de esta manera generamos el switch en python, con un diccionario que es una estructura de datos"""
def switch(case, a, b):
    sw = {
        1: suma(a, b),
        2: resta(a, b),
        3: multiplicacion(a, b),
        4: division(a, b),
    }
    return sw.get(case, default())

"""y creamos un menú de llamado a las funciones según lo que se queira hacer"""    
def menu():
    print("----------- Calculadora -----------")
    print("1. Suma")
    print("2. Resta")
    print("3. Multiplicacion")
    print("4. Division")
    print("-----------------------------------")

"""aquí capturamos los valores de a y b"""
a = int(input("Valor de a: "))
b = int(input("Valor de b: "))
"""mostramos el menú y luego capturamos la opción de llamado y eso llamará a la función"""
menu()
case = int(input("Seleccione una opcion: "))
print(switch(case, a, b))
```

Así te evitarías if anidados

Answer (score 3):

Si hablamos de algo más o menos dinámico, hay algunas alternativas. En primer lugar, lo más simple es manejar un diccionario propio de "mapeo" `{cadena: función}`. Algo como esto:

```
def abrir():
  print("abrir")

def cerrar():
  print("cerrar")

funciones = {"abrir": abrir, "cerrar": cerrar}

funcion = funciones["abrir"]
funcion()
```

Accedemos al diccionario por la cadena y el valor del mismo es la función. Algo muy parecido es usar [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) y/o [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) solo que estas funciones ya nos retornan el diccionario interno de **python** para los objetos del modulo actual o los globales:

```
locals()["abrir"]()
globals()["cerrar"]()
```

Tener en cuenta que [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) en el contexto de una función apunta a los objetos de la misma. Finalmente, puedes usar [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
import sys
result = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], 'abrir')()
```

La invocación básica es `getattr(<modulo>, <nombre objeto>)` lo cual nos da más control ya que podemos especificar exactamente de que módulo es el objeto que vamos a invocar. En este ejemplo `sys.modules[__name__]` nos da el actual desde dónde hacemos la llamada.

**Importante**: si quieres generalizar la llamada, es obvio, pero no esta de más decirlo, que los parámetros de la función deberían ser consistentes entre todas ellas.

Fuentes:

- [Calling a function of a module by using its name (a string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)
- [How do I call setattr() on the current module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933470/how-do-i-call-setattr-on-the-current-module)